# Implementing Observer in View (Java)

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am trying to implement the Observer pattern into my program that uses the MVC pattern. I am doing this so that the View can see any changes that I may do in the Model (I am to later perform a scanner input and append to the already existing hashmap). But I am struggling with how to implement the Observer into my program.

Here is the view:

```
package product.view;

import product.controller.Controller;

public class View{
    private Controller cont;

    public View(Controller cont) {
        this.cont = cont;
    }

    public void test() {
        cont.makeNewSale();
        enterItem(1);
    }

    private void enterItem(int itemId)  {
        int quantity = 1;

        try {   
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Result for item " + itemId + ": " + cont.enterItem(itemId, quantity));
            System.out.println("");
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `ProductCatalogue` in Model:

```
package product.model;

import java.util.Map;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class ProductCatalog { 
    private Map<Integer, ProductSpecification> products = new HashMap<Integer, ProductSpecification>();


    public ProductCatalog() {
        products.put(1, new ProductSpecification(1, "low fat milk", 
   "a very long description, a very long description, a very long description", 10));
        products.put(2, new ProductSpecification(2, "butter", 
   "a very long description, a very long description, a very long description", 10));
        products.put(3, new ProductSpecification(3, "bread", 
   "a very long description, a very long description, a very long description", 10));
        System.out.println(products.toString());
    }

    public ProductSpecification findSpecification(int itemId) {
        return products.get(itemId);
    }

    boolean findSpecification() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to pass the controller as a parameter to the constructor of the view?

Comment: Indeed, why not model?

Comment: Because I want all calls to go from the controller to the model.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [UML class diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Observer.svg) for the observer pattern:
[image]

It shows you what methods you need and even parts of the implementation.
Basically speaking, the model holds a list of objects which it will call a certain method on.

Your problem is that you are not following the pattern precisely and mixing concerns.
The `controller` decides what happens upon user input. The `view` should not tell the `controller` what to do, it should merely inform him, that there's some user input.